# Stacking items with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, positioning

In my header, I'm trying to put my name in the middle item below the first item "brush up". I've tried `justify-content` and `align-items` and just can't get it to move. I also want the navigation to stay on the right side. New to flexbox thank you for any help.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/* HEADER SECTION***************************************/

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

header * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

header h1 {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  flex: 3;
}

header p {
  flex: 2;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  height: 25px;
  align-items: baseline;
}

header ul {
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  list-style-type: none;
}

header ul li {
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Brushing up</h1>
  <p>by Keller Johnson</p>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">project 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">project 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

header, header > * {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

header > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
header > ul {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  list-style-type: none;
}

header * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header h1 {
  height: 50px;
}

header p {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  height: 25px;
}

header ul li {
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    <h1>Brushing up</h1>
    <p>by Keller Johnson</p>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">project 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">project 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

If this is not the result you want, consider explaining more clearly exactly what you're trying to achieve. Since we're talking about styling, a picture would help.

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I needed. Will look into the shorthand property more for "flex:". I'll be more specific next time as well.