# CSS: Stacking two divs which are inside different containers without using position Absolute

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, grid

I have a switch with a label and a hint. But the label should be clickable, whereas the hint should not.
Hence the label container is wrapped inside a  but the hint container is not.
I need the Label and the Hint to stack and be aligned but both have variable widths.
Here is the markup in case you happen to have an idea.
I have tried it with flexbox, but If I give the hint container a margin-left, it will not be aligned once the label is wider, because of more content. I have tried with position "absolute" and it works, but then it will be a problem because I also have to account for custom labels that are placed at the left of the switch.  I am thankful for any help

```
<div class="container" >
   <label class="trial">
       <div class="switch__container">
           <input class="input" type="checkbox"
           />
               <span class="switch"></span>
       </div>
         <div class="switch__label-container">
             <span class="switch__label">
               {{ label }}
             </span>
         </div>
     </label>
     <div class="switch__hint-container">
         <span v-if="hint || $slots.hint" class="switch__hint">
             <slot name="hint">
               {{ hint }}
             </slot>
         </span>
     </div>
 </div>
```

I have tried with `grid` as mentioned in this solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73256577/stacking-items-with-flexbox[![But](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73256577/stacking-items-with-flexbox%5B!%5BBut) it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlAGh.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlAGh.png)

```
.container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr 1fr;
   border: 1px solid green;
   align-items: self-start;
   min-height: 48px;
   justify-content: left;
}

.trial {
    display: grid;
}

.switch__container {
    width: 56px;
    height: 48px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 8px 5px 5px 5px;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    grid-column: span 3;
}
.switch__label-container {
    grid-row: span 2;
}

.switch__hint-container {
    grid-row: span 2;
}
```

I have also tried with flexbox , and it sort of works, but if the label is longer the hint gets misaligned with respect to the label.

Comment: Could you make your code into a runnable snippet - I'm slightly struggling to understand what is going on/required. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Are you not able to change the markup?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to have fully understand, but I tried something with grid.

Only 1 grid, not nested grid.

I split your 1 block of 2 elements in 2 elements.

You need 3 columns, I put 4 total, 3 first are auto (meaning auto fit), last 1 is fr, it will take the remaining space.

Perhaps It's not eaxctly what you're looking, but it's a beginning, tell me...

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  border: 1px solid green;
  align-items: self-start;
  min-height: 48px;
  justify-content: left;
}

.trial {
  display: grid;
}

.switch__container {
  width: 56px;
  height: 48px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 5px 5px 5px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.switch__label-container {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.switch__hint-container {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label class="trial">
        <div class="switch__container">
            <input class="input" type="checkbox"/>
            <span class="switch"></span>
        </div>
    </label>
  <div class="switch__label-container">
    <span class="switch__label">
               {{ label }}
             </span>
  </div>
  <div class="switch__hint-container">
    <span v-if="hint || $slots.hint" class="switch__hint">
             <slot name="hint">
               {{ hint }}
             </slot>
         </span>
  </div>
</div>
```